# Vue.js async update from inside JS import

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, vue.js

I have two form components, which have a common JS validator.

```
import { validateInput } from './validateInput.js'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      email: 'a@a.com',
      validEmail: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    validateInput
  },
  watch: {
    'email': function (val) {
       this.validEmail = validateInput('email', val)
                         // ^ makes async request
    }
  }
}
```

The validator uses `jQuery.ajax` - async HTTP request to server. The problem is that, since `validateInput()` is asynchronous, it returns before it gets a response from the server (`this.validEmail` is undefined)
How do I update the Vue instance (`this.validEmail`) after the async request in this JS imported function is completed?

In simple terms - how do I access the Vue instance from inside `validateInput` in a way that works asynchronously?

I've tried passing the Vue instance as an argument, doesn't update:

```
validateInput('email', val, this)
----
// validateInput.js
email() {
  $.ajax({
    ...
    success(response) {
      vueInstance.validEmail = response   // doesn't work
    }
  })
  vueInstance.validEmail = false
         // ^^^^ this works
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
watch: {
    'email': function (val) {
       validateInput('email', val,this)
    }
  }
```

and

```
validateInput('email', val, ref)
----
// validateInput.js
email() {
  $.ajax({
    ...
    success(response) {
      ref.validEmail = response   // doesn't work
    }
  })
         // ^^^^ this works
}
```

Or the traditional way to deal with asynchronous calls is pass a callback that has a closure over the variable that needs edited.

```
watch: {
    'email': function (val) {
       validateInput('email', val,function(response){this.validEmail=response})
    }
  }
  //...
  validateInput('email', val, cb)
  //...
  success(response) {
    cb(response);
  }
```

Comment: Also, he can use 

    `Vue.set(vueInstance, 'validEmail', response);`